# How to fix this error in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

> Warning   IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.
>
> Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "ADODB". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.
>
> The referenced component 'adodb1' could not be found.

Comment: A useful search expression in your favorite search engine might be `Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "ADODB"`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your missing a reference to ActiveX Data Objects in your project? It's part of the MS Data Access Components (MDAC).